# Run Wallch in background

Tags: desktop-background

New to the Ubuntu scene. Is it possible to get Wallch to run in the background? Because when I'm running Wallch right now I have to start it up then bar it and leave it running for the time I'm on the computer. Is there a way to "hide" it?

Answer (score 3):

[Wallch]

Edit > Preferences > General:

- ☑ Hide app when 'start' is pressed
- ☑ Unity ProgressBar